# Insert element last into list

Tags: list, sml

How do you insert an element (in this case, a char) into a list so it ends up as the last element?

For example, say that I want to add `#"D"` as the last element in the list `[#"A, #"B", #"C"]` so I then would have `[#"A, #"B", #"C", #"D"]`.

(This should also work for inserting a string containing more than one element: adding `[#"D", #"E"]` should give `[#"A, #"B", #"C", #"D", #"E"]`.)

Comment: The word you are looking for is "append" - http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/sml/intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Just append it to the end using "@".

```
 [#"A", #"B", #"C"] @ [#"D"]
```